# Getting started with Prism (Ent Lib v5) and building an app framework

Tags: wpf, frameworks, enterprise-library, bootstrapper, prism-2

Can anyone point me to any useful examples of an application framework being built using the newly released Enterprise Library 5?

I have previously used v4.1 and after downloading the source for v5 and building - I'm not understanding how to integrate it with a WPF app - i.e. there doesn't appear to be any UnityBootstrapper class.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i.e. there doesn't appear to be any
>   UnityBootstrapper class.

If the problem is that you can't find UnityBootstrapper, you can find it in the UnityExtensions Dll (Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.dll). 
It's been moved from the Prism dll because of the introduction of [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.mefbootstrapper%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx).

You can also use the [MefBootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.mefbootstrapper%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx), from Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.dll.